# How to get description in this json format using php?

Tags: php, json

How to get description in this json format using php ?

This is json data

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "DHHlQxea3Pg",
   "snippet": {
    "description": "Private Jet trip to the Rocky Mountains 1080p"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

and this is my code

```
$curl_json_video_description = curl_init('some url');
curl_setopt($curl_json_video_description, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json_video_description = curl_exec($curl_json_video_description);
$result_json_video_description = json_decode($json_video_description);
$video_description = $result_json_video_description->items->snippet->description;
echo $video_description;
```

When i test my code it's not echo anything, how can i do for get description in json ?

Comment: The "items" node is an array, so if you want to access the first element, you wanna use `$result_json_video_description->items[0]->snippet->description`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `0` item key, because `items` is array of items.

Use `$result_json_video_description->items[0]->snippet->description`

*OR* Decode it as array `json_decode($json, true)` and then:

```
$result_json_video_description = json_decode();

$result_json_video_description['items'][0]['snippet']['description']
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me :)

```
$content = file_get_contents('url');
$jsonize = json_decode($content, true);

echo $jsonize['items'][0]['snippet']['description'];
```